# Replace NA in nested list if at least one of the values in the nested list is not NA

Tags: r

I have two versions of the same nested list (or list of lists). Each list in the nested list contains different amounts of vectors (vectors contain only integers).

- A "complete" version with all data in the lists
- A "missing" version -  same as the complete version but some of the integers are randomly replaced with NA

Some example data:

```
#complete list
L.full<-list(list(1,3,c(0,2,0),c(0,0)),list(1,6,c(0,3,2,0,1,0),c(0,0,0,1,0,0),1,2,c(0,1),2,c(0,0)),
     list(1,0),list(1,0),list(1,4,c(2,0,0,0),c(4,1),c(1,0,0,0,0),0))

#"randomly" allocated NAs
L.miss<-list(list(1,3,c(0,NA,0),c(0,0)),list(1,6,c(0,3,NA,0,NA,0),c(0,NA,0,1,0,0),1,NA,c(0,1),2,c(0,0)),
             list(NA,NA),list(1,0),list(1,NA,c(NA,0,0,0),c(NA,NA),c(1,0,0,NA,0),0))
```

I would now like to go back through the list containing NA values and give the original numbers a 'second chance' by reassigning the original value in `L.miss` (the original from `L.full`) according to some binomial probability `p2`. The catch is that it should have this second chance *only if at least one integer in the nested list is not NA*. For instance, in `L.miss`, the 3rd position (i.e. `L.miss[[3]]`) would not get this 'second chance' as all vectors in the list contain all `NA` values. All other positions in `L.miss` would have the opportunity to get reassigned the original number since they have at least one non-NA integer in the nested list.

For instance, if p2=1, then all `NA` values would be replaced with the original, except for those lists that contain all `NA` values (this is particularly likely when the nested list of vectors is small (i.e. n=2)). If p2=0, then no `NA` values would be replaced.

I have tried utilizing the fact that a vector of `NA` values is a logical type, not numeric, but I keep hitting a dead end.

I wrote the below function that uses the example `L.miss` and `L.full` from above and replaces all `NA` values with some probability `p2`.

```
##' @param L.full is the complete nested list (i.e. from above)
##' @param L.miss is the imperfect nested list (i.e. from above)
##' @param p2 is the "second chance" probability

second.chance<-function(L.miss,L.full,p2){
  sec.chance<-list()
#Get down to the individual values in the nested lists (of varying lengths)
  for (i in 1:length(L.miss)){
    for (j in 1:length(L.miss[[i]])){
      for (k in 1:length(L.miss[[i]][[j]])){
        for (l in 1:length(L.miss[[i]][[j]][[k]])){
          #If the value is NA, assign the original value with some binomial probability p2
          if (is.na(L.miss[[i]][[j]][[k]])){
            sec.chance[l]<-rbinom(1,1,p2)
            if (sec.chance[l]==1){
              L.miss[[i]][[j]][[k]]<-L.full[[i]][[j]][[k]]
            } else{L.miss[[i]][[j]][[k]]<-NA}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(L.miss)
}
#An example to test. If p2 is set to 1.0, all NA values are replaced. If set to 0.0, none are replaced
L.test<-second.chance(L.full=L.full, L.miss=L.miss, p2=0.5)
```

This reassigns the original value, but indiscriminately. I am not sure how (or where) to add in the capability for it to first evaluate the nested list for all `NA` values and then run the "second chance" probability if it is not all `NA`s. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process:

```
x<-sapply(L.miss, function(x) all(is.na(unlist(x))))
```

creates a logical vector. In the stepwise process, create a temporary row bound list :

```
temp<-rbind(L.miss,sapply(z.pass, function(x) all(is.na(unlist(x)))))
```

This has the logical info after every nested list (i.e. the logical information for `L.miss[[2]]` will be in `temp[[4]]` - put it in a loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(L.miss)){
    if (temp[[i*2]]==TRUE){
        L.want[i]<-L.miss[i]
        } 
        else{ 
      for (j in 1:length(L.miss[[i]])){
        for (k in 1:length(L.miss[[i]][[j]])){
          for (l in 1:length(L.miss[[i]][[j]][[k]])){
            #See if the individual position in the nested list is an NA value
            if (is.na(L.miss[[i]][[j]][[k]])){
              if(runif(1)<p2){ #Stochastic process to determine if it should proceed
                L.want[[i]][[j]][[k]]<-L.full[[i]][[j]][[k]] #reassign original value
              }}}}}}}
```